# QGIS QgsOgrProvider library

Tags: qgis, ogr, library

I asked a question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790463/qgis-copy-layer-in-c-plugin
and I was suggested to find the library which provides `QgsOgrProvider::createEmptyLayer()` function.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find `libogrprovider.so` and link against it:

```
g++ code_out.o -o yourapp -L/path/to/qgis/PlugIns/qgis/ -logrprovider
```